# jQuery $() constructor and strings with a leading backslash

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please, take a look at this code: http://jsfiddle.net/Bkdgr/1/

It does not work. However, either of the following two modifications makes it work correctly: 

Passing the pure `newItem` string in `append`, instead of wrapping it with `$()`:

```
$('button').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var newItem = '\
        <li>Hello, \
        World!</li>';
    $('ul').append(newItem);
});
```

Moving the opening `<li>` tag up to the first line of the string definition:

```
$('button').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var newItem = '<li>Hello, \
        World!</li>';
    $('ul').append($(newItem));
});
```

Neither does it work when I move up `<li>` to the same line with the leading `\` (but without deleting `\`).
To me, it seems like the `$()` constructor has some problem with the leading `\` in string definitions. Passing pure string (without `$()` wrapper) into `append` doesn't seem to cause any problem.
Why does it work like this? Does a leading slash have any special meaning in `$()`?

Comment: Just to be clear, your string does not have a leading backslash, it has a leading newline character (and possibly a return). The backslash just escapes the newline character so that the javascript parser can parse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

html strings being parsed by jQuery with `$()` can't have leading spaces or newline/return characters, or even just plain text. This is documented in the api.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

If it's an HTML string, it **must** start with an html tag. `.append()` and `.html()` are a little less strict because the passed in string can't be parsed as a css selector.

Comment: Interestingly enough, jQuery versions before 1.9 were more forgiving about this. If you change the fiddle to use 1.7.2 or 1.8.3, the code works even with the leading spaces. It also works in 1.6.4 if you chanage the `.on` to `.bind`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide if you want to use $() as constructor. If so you need to provide tag as first element in string. It also check for close tag and add it if needed.
If you need you code to work, just do not use constructor if you provide custom HTML code:
`$('ul').append(newItem)`.

You can also divide it like this:

```
    $('button').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var newItem = '\
            Hello, \
            World!';
        $("<li>").html(newItem).appendTo("ul");
    });
```

You need to play with jQuery not against it :)